# Software made with Quickly is missing an icon in the Dash

Tags: 11.10, application-development, icons, quickly

I am currently trying out Quickly create.

When issuing `quickly package` it packages fine and I can install the deb.

Only thing is, there is no icon in the dash for my program. How do I go about making one?

I was told Quickly takes care of this but in my case this doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Rick Spencer's blog entry on [creating a desktop file](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2011/02/easily-support-sound-menu-in-python.html).
That example is showing far more than just creating a desktop file, but you can use that part to do what you want to do. It's a few extra steps, but rather straightforward.

Comment: did this work smittix?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for the delay in replying. I didn't have any notification of a reply :/

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this myself:

1. quickly create ubuntu-application tester
2. cd tester
3. quickly package
4. sudo dpkg -i ../tester_0.1_all.deb
5. Search in the dash for "tester" and it appeared with an icon

When your deb file is created and installed, do you have a file like (e.g.) /usr/share/tester/media/tester.svg ?

Does your desktop file refer to it?  (Look at the Icon line in /usr/share/applications/tester.desktop)

Obviously, replace tester in the above filenames with your app name.